# Rails color_field: select initial picker mode (HEX instead of RGB)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

I need to customize Rails `color_field` picker to open in `HEX` mode initially. Its current default mode is RGB, but want to limit picker mode to `HEX` only.

[image: color_field picker]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the default HTML5 form field attributes, that picker is implemented by the client (browser) and you have no control over how it presents itself to the user.

Off topic: This is a good thing. The client should work for—and be under control of—the user, not the content provider.